# How to see if a value changed within an amount of time?

Tags: c#

I'm using an asynchronous method that sets a value. I want to see if the value remains the same within 10 seconds. If the value didn't change in this amount of time, it should enable a flag to do something else.

Is there a simple way to do it?

The timer should start when the value is changed and be checked (let's say maybe not every time which would be overkill but every 0.5 seconds) until the timer reached 10 seconds and then execute a method or change the value of a flag to false for example.

As I tried with another async method to be triggered when the value changed it didn't work. And it seemed to me to be very complicated to do.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Asynchronously sends the commands to CWI
    /// </summary>
    private async void SendCommandToCWI(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {

            //Here is some logic that will calculate many things to get the value of _axisX and _axisY.
           //I deleted this part to show the code as it was unnecessary. 

            if (!(_axisX == 0 && _axisY == 0) && (PortVM != null) && PortVM.IsOpen)
            {
                CommandSender.AxisX(_axisX);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                string indata = PortVM.ReadExisting();
                //Debug.Print("Data Received:");
                //Debug.Print(indata);
                Console.WriteLine(_axisY);
                Console.WriteLine(_axisX);
                CommandSender.AxisY(_axisY);
            }
            else
            {
                PanelX = 0;
                PanelY = 0;
                _TimerInside.Stop();
                _axisX = 0;
                _axisY = 0;                       
                CommandSender.AxisX(0);
                CommandSender.AxisY(0);
                CommandSender.AxisX(_axisX);
                CommandSender.AxisY(_axisY);
            }
        });
    }
```

So basically I want to see if every time I calculate `_axisX` and `_axisY` that after 10 seconds if the results remains the same it should whatever call a method or set a flag from true to false.

Comment: you can use an _axisX and _axisY as properties and call Some event when in it's set accessor. For example, you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged event

Comment: Can you not do something like this (pseudo-code): `original_var = 1` `temp = original_var` start timer and perform calculations which change the value of original_var then `if temp == original_var` do something

Comment: @Polly I already have NotifyPropertyChanged for these, but if `_axisX` is set to 2, the NotifyPropertyChanged will be triggerd. But also when it is set to 2 again after the first time so it won't work in theory.

Comment: @JordanSavage Basically no, as the whole calculations is done every Xms as it is inside a async method

Comment: This is based on your implementation. If you call PropertyChanged event only if value is different from previous value - then yes, it wouldn't work. If you call PropertyChanged event each time - it will

Comment: @Polly I see, i'm going to try this out.

Comment: You need to save the previous value so you have something to compare against.